# SQL Query to modify the order of columns individually without affecting whole table based on matching values with another column

Tags: sql, join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to write a SQL Query where I have a table and I have three columns with similar distinct values. I want to order the 2nd and 3rd columns in such a way that the rows where all 3 columns match are in the same row and the ones where even if any 1 column does not match it will modify its order. For eg-

Table TEMP-

```
COLA COLB COLC COLD
100  100  AA   null
100  100  CC   BB
100  100  DD   CC
100  100  EE   DD
100  100  null FF
100  100  FF   GG
100  100  HH   null
```

I want the output to be like -

```
COLA COLB COLC COLD
100  100  AA   null
100  100  CC   CC
100  100  DD   DD
100  100  FF   FF
100  100  EE   BB
100  100  null GG
100  100  HH   null
```

All the matching values should be together. The non matching values can be different.

I tried to do inner join on the same table but it only gave the matching column in the following manner -

```
select t1.COLA,t2.COLB,t1.COLC,t2.COLD
from TEMP t1
inner join TEMP t2
  on t1.COLA = t2.COLB and t1.COLC = t2.COLD;
```

I got the following result -

```
COLA COLB COLC COLD
100  100  CC   CC
100  100  DD   DD
100  100  FF   FF
100  100  EE   BB
```

I need the rows for the unmatched columns as well. Please provide a SQL Query.

Comment: I, for one, don't understand your requirement. Here's a [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8HzvWvD7m9y1mkfUCNX89N/0) showing your example.

Comment: @O.Jones Apologies for not being clear enough in the text, but I just want my output to be exactly like the one I described instead of what I get.

Comment: I understood you want to keep matching records, but why EE   BB is match? can you explain what is logic required for that

Comment: @ADITYAPAWAR only 3 records are a match. EE BB is not a match. BB does not have to be alongside EE. it can be anywhere. But the matching 3 records should be side by side.

Answer (score 0):

I do not really get what you are trying to achieve ...
But you definitely don't wanna be using an `INNER JOIN` because you will only get all data which has values in both tables.

I suggest you try a `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

Read more about the difference between all the joins here: https://www.coursera.org/articles/sql-join-types#